# Organizing Access Objects Into Custom Groups/Categories

Tags: ms-access, categories, ms-access-2010

So within Access, the column on the far left is organized by `Tables`, `Queries`, `Forms` and `Reports`. Within those groups, are obviously all the tables, queries, etc that you've created.

Is there any way to add custom groups within each? So for example, you have a table for Carrots, Onions, Strawberries and Grapes. Is it possible to create groups/categories called "Fruit" and "Vegetables", keeping all the "Fruit" tables together and vice versa?

Comment: How can using MS Access as a development tool be off-topic?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: It is a question for people voting to close.

Comment: Voting to close this question?

Comment: Where do you look to find out if people are voting to close your question?

Comment: It is not visible until you are allowed to vote to close.

Comment: @Remou - I'm interested in knowing this as well. I'm curious about how/where you _specifically_ are seeing that people are voting to close this question.

Comment: @Yawar see meta and the faq http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83742/is-the-faq-wrong-re-the-ability-to-vote-to-close-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose custom from the drop down list:

[image: custom]

Once you have chosen Custom, you can choose to add objects to groups using right-click:

[image: custom 2]

Groups can be renamed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this link helpful as well, along with Remou's response. Shows a different way of creating custom groups.

[Manage database objects in the Navigation Pane](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/manage-database-objects-in-the-navigation-pane-HA010342108.aspx)

Comment: Posted link is dead.